# Finding cos of both known and unknown constants

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm sure there's a very simple solution here, but I'm somewhat new to trigonometry and it hasn't hit me yet.

I have the function $\cos(-20-c) = 0.084$, where $c$ is a constant, and $-20$ is the value I'm substituting in for my $x$ value. I need to solve for $c$, so is there some way I am able to split this function into $\cos(-20)$ and $\cos c$? I need them to divided, multiplied, etc. so that together they still equal $0.084$.

Comment: You could use $cos(a+b) = cos(a)cos(b)-sin(a)sin(b)$

Comment: Can you not apply the inverse of cosine on both sides?

Comment: Do you have a calculator, dragon, with an inverse cosine button on it?

Comment: Use $cos{(-20-c)}=cos{(20+c)}$ then use the sum expansion and replace the $sin{(c)}$